# Can Castle Windsor register types from dynamic assemblies?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a dynamically generated assembly that has been created using Reflection.Emit.  I am then trying to register controller types from that assembly using Windsor in the following way:

`WindsorContainer.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(myDynamicAssembly).BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());`

When I try to navigate to an endpoint specified in the one of these controllers I get the following error:

```
[NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetExportedTypes() +68
Castle.Core.Internal.ReflectionUtil.GetAvailableTypes(Assembly assembly, Boolean includeNonExported) +74
Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromAssemblyDescriptor.&lt;SelectedTypes&gt;b__0(Assembly a) +21
System.Linq.&lt;SelectManyIterator&gt;d__14`2.MoveNext() +267
Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) +296
Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) +72
Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) +50
```

Is it just not possible to register anything in a dynamic assembly or is there some other issue that I'm missing?

Note that without Windsor (ie using the default controller activator service) the assembly/controllers/endpoints works correctly.  I can possibly use Windsor's DynamicProxy functionality instead of the Reflection.Emit approach but I would like to exhaust all possibilities with this current approach before I tackle that somewhat daunting task!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you aren't missing anything. Currently this is not supported by Windsor.

As the stack trace indicates, where you do `Classes.FromAssembly(myDynamicAssembly)` Windsor uses `Assembly.GetExportedTypes` to look for types to register and as [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) states, this method isn't supported on dynamic assemblies.

Windsor uses `GetExportedTypes` to not have to waste time looking at non-public classes, since it by default only allow public classes to be registered.

You can however override it by adding `. IncludeNonPublicTypes()` which doesn't use `Assembly.GetExportedTypes` and will stop the exception from occurring. The side-effect of that is, that now Windsor will register any potential non-public classes meeting your specified criteria (`BasedOn<ApiController>()` so if you want to avoid that you will have to filter those out yourself.

So for completeness, here's how your registration will look:

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromAssembly(myDynamicAssembly)
      .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
      .BasedOn<ApiController>()
      .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

I guess there is no good reason why Windsor shouldn't handle dynamic assemblies out of the box, so perhaps you'd like to open an issue for it and have a crack at pull requesting it?

Comment: Having "IncludeNonPublicTypes()" seems pretty OOB .. it's just a matter of container configuration, not 'lack of' support.